# Magento - Rename Tax to GST

Tags: product, admin, magento-1, tax, localisation

Throughout my Magento website, where there are products, I made it so that a customer can see the price of the products, with and without Tax.

However, how can I rename the word 'Tax' to 'GST' whenever a product is viewed within the website. I believe I have to go to the back-end and change some script around, I just don't know where?

Comment: Assuming that GST is not an American name for tax, but specific to pacific nations, you could change your locale for the store view to where it should apply

Comment: I found something you can follow for GST India set up https://magecomp.com/blog/create-gst-tax-rule-magento/

Comment: Got the extension too https://magecomp.com/magento-indian-gst.html

Answer (score 5):

You have two options (modifying core files does not count)

1. **Database based approach, using admin panel:**

   Use inline translations. In `System > Configuration > Advanced > Developer` you can activate translation mode. If your site is publicly accessible, make sure to enter your IP address in "Developer Client Restrictions", otherwise anybody can change translations:

   [image: Screenshot]

   Then you can click on the translation icon [image: Translation Icon] next to each translatable string and change the translation:

   [image: Screenshot]
2. **File based approach, using theme translations:**

   This approach is useful if you want to change translations based on the theme instead of globally, and if you want to keep changes under version control. Create the file `locale/en_US/translate.csv` in your theme directory below `app/design` if it does not exist and add the following line:

   ```
   "Mage_Tax::Tax","GST"
   ```

   It should be noted that only one `translate.csv` is used at a time, using the theme fallback mechanisms. So if you have one in `package/default` and in `package/custom`, only the latter is used.

Comment: perfect answer with better explanations :) +1

Answer (score 1):

Follow this steps

1) Go to this file : `\app\locale\en_US\Mage_Tax.csv`.

2) Replace all **`Tax`** string with **`GST`** string ***only in the second-column***,

3) Refresh magento cache.

**Note** - Make sure you are using `en_US` as *locale*. If something else go that your locale folder and update same file.

Answer (score 0):

To update 'TAX' title in customer's order confirmation email, update in below file:
/app/design/frontend/base/default/template/tax/order/tax.phtml

line number 94:

echo $this->__('Tax');

Repleace above line to

echo "NEW TAX TITLE";

Hope it helps you!