# Custom Backorder Message

Tags: cart, localisation, backorder

How it's possible to change the Backorder cart message???

I'd need to display something like "The product will be available to ship from the 1st of january"

Thx

Comment: Globally change the message or change it per product or based on some rules?

Comment: for me globally change it's enough, because I have only one product to apply backorder...

Comment: ... for the future and for others, also the per product change might be very useful...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The string is translated in the `Mage_CatalogInventory` module as "This product is not available in the requested quantity. %s of the items will be backordered."

You can change it using theme translation or inline translation as described here: [Magento - Rename Tax to GST](https://magento.stackexchange.com/q/52652/243)

For the theme translation approach, you need the following line in `translate.csv`:

```
"Mage_CatalogInventory::This product is not available in the requested quantity. %s of the items will be backordered.","The product will be available to ship from the 1st of january"
```

Answer (score 1):

@fschmengler your answer was very helpful, however for my magento install I needed a slightly different code in the end for the translation file:

`"""%s"" is not available in the requested quantity. %s of the items will be backordered.","new message here"`

Perhaps this is due to my theme or different magento versions (I'm on CE 1.9.0.1)

Comment: I do not have enough reputation to comment on your answer