# Magento Rename Tax To GST For Multi designer store

Tags: magento-1.9

I want to change tax word into GST. how will change?

Answer (score 1):

Change in database at tax_calculation_rule table

[image]

This will change from Tax to GST at all locations

Answer (score 0):

Create file if it does not exist : `app/design/frontend/VENDOR/THEME/locale/en_US/translate.csv`

and add the following line:

```
"Mage_Tax::Tax","GST"
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of answer https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/52652/magento-rename-tax-to-gst

Comment: @emipro Instead of giving a duplicate answer please post link of an answer. That will give more information about topic.